# Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS 32-bit Update Issue with 4.4.0-186-generic

Tags: 16.04, wireless

On Thursday, July 24, 2020, I updated Linux software (I do this regularly) and on Friday, July 25, 2020 my computer (ancient Dell Dimension E520) would not recognize the USB network adapter (TP-Link TL-WN722N).

When I keyed in $ lsusb, the network adapter was shown. However, through $ dmesg, I saw that the wireless network driver ath9k_htc was not functioning.

When I manually boot to 4.4.0-185-generic, the network adapter works fine.

Should I purge 4.4.0-186-generic, or keep manually booting to 4.4-185-generic until fixes are applied?

Thanks,

DHowell725

P.S. I have not updated to Ubuntu 18.04 because my system operates at only 1.86 GHz.

Per the kind feedback of chili555, here is the what I think is the most relevant information from

```
$ dsmeg:

[    5.689420] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[   25.689532] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   25.903166] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   26.833068] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[   27.085439] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[   27.378166] gpio_ich: GPIO from 462 to 511 on gpio_ich
[   29.781268] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   29.781275] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   29.781277] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)




[   34.962616] Adding 2093052k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2093052k FS
[   35.712552] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   51.278746] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   51.476255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  116.336460] audit_printk_skb: 87 callbacks suppressed
[  116.336465] audit: type=1400 audit(1596037822.260:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/share/hplip/systray.py" name="/snap/bin/" pid=1564 comm="hp-upgrade" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  116.346453] audit: type=1400 audit(1596037822.268:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/share/hplip/systray.py" name="/bin/ping" pid=1566 comm="hp-upgrade" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  133.698756] ath9k_htc: Failed to initialize the device
[  133.698972] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
```

Comment: Good job troubleshooting! 1) Keep booting the older kernel. 2) File a bug report against the `linux` package.

Comment: "I saw that the wireless network driver ath9k_htc was not functioning." Please edit your question to show the exact output that shows this, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much user535733. I am trying to figure out how and where to file the report and hope to complete the task today.

Comment: Chili555: Thank you very much  for your comment and I have added what I think is the relevant information from $ dsmeg.

Answer (score 0):

In early August, I reported the problem through kernel.org bugzilla. Yesterday (5 September) I downloaded system updates and today (6 September) I booted with the newly added 4.4.0-189-generic. My network adapter works with this new kernel.